# What is a Stateful Mobility and Stateless?

Tags: architecture

Excerpt from my architecture book:

> If a software module that needs to be migrated contains runtime state, then the module’s migration is known as stateful mobility
>
> If only the code needs to be migrated, that is known as stateless
>   mobility

What is a runtime state in this context? can someone give me an example for each case?

Comment: This probably belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ rather than StackOverflow -- being, as it is, about concepts behind programming rather than code.

Comment: Functional languages tend to force a great deal of thinking about state and how it's managed, by the way -- if you want to be good at managing state, using a language in which almost everything is immutable (and any update to state is through an explicit -- and atomic -- operation) is an effective way to learn the skillset, even if you end up using more conventional tools later. Writing code the traditional OO way tends to lead to state being strewn about everywhere with little coordination -- very much a mess in comparison.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Is there a way to move the question?

Comment: Since Programmers isn't an available migration option (the set of options is based on the statistics for number of accepted/successful migrations), migrating requires involvement of one of the elected moderators -- one can flag the question (with flag type "other") and request that a moderator consider it for migration. If you'd like more/better answers, that's probably worth doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Runtime state" is just that -- information known at runtime.

Let's say that you're running a game. If you have information about each player in memory on the server, and need to route requests about that player through the same server, your game is stateful.

If you keep information about a player's state on the client (hopefully signed or encrypted to prevent cheating!) and submit that information with every request, then your server is stateless -- everything it needs to know to process a request is part of that request.

If you keep information in a database, this muddies the waters a bit -- your *system* (of which the database is a component) is stateful (the database contains its state), but the *individual service* may be stateless (if it retrieves all necessary information from the database on each request).

Caching behaviors muddy the waters a bit -- as they're state, but state you don't necessarily need to care about when migrating between servers (except at risk of taking some amount of performance hit). Thus, for service mobility purposes, one may choose not to count caches as state.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you other than ticking as correct answer! Caching example is exactly what I needed to make the whole picture clear!